# Export Access Table To Azure SQL Error related to Datetime2 type

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I tried to export an access table to Azure SQL and it gives me the following error:

> "Microsoft Access was unable to append all the data to the table.  The
>   contents of fields in 1 records(s) were deleted, and 0 records(s) were
>   lost due to key violations. *If data was deleted, the data you pasted
>   or imported doesn't match the field data types or the FieldSize
>   property in the destination table...."

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "ODBC Database", "ODBC;Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL server;Server=*******;Database=****;Uid=***;Pwd=***;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;", acTable, "MyAccessTestTable", "ServerTestTable", , False
```

My table has only one field [CreateDate] with value of (7/7/2017 11:31:34 AM). After checking with SQL, the table is created and it is blank. The date field is Datetime2 field type.

It seems that when I export the table, Azure SQL create Datetime2 type and it is causing the problem. Is there a setting in Azure SQL to default the new datetime type to datetime instead of Datetime2 when I export a table?

Thanks for all your expert suggestions.

Comment: Is the field a `DateTime2(0)`, a `DateTime2(7)` field, or something in between?  You may be trying to add a value with milliseconds into a field that doesn't handle the milliseconds.

Comment: Also, is the field blank or `NULL`?

Comment: Thanks, Laughing Vergil. The field is DateTime2(7). Also there is zero rows in the table. I guess SQL server create the structure first and then try to insert the data and it failed. Since I am using DoCmd.TransferDatabase everywhere in my Access, I have to rewrite the whole application.

Comment: Hi, finally I find a solution with my Access export problem to SQL Azure. I have to reset all my date fields to smalldatetime in all my SQL tables. After that, when I import data to Access and export them back again, there are no error messages. It seems SQL Azure create datatime type instead of datetime2 type which was causing the error.